# 'grunt compass' throwing error that it's not in the system PATH

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm pretty new to using grunt, compass, and sass and am having trouble getting it to work. I have a Redhat installation with Drupal 7 and when I try to run 'grunt compass' from within the site's theme directory I get the following error:

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task     to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've installed Grunt, Bower, and used 'bundle install' to install the needed gems. When I run 'gem list' I get the following:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
breakpoint (2.0.7)
bundler (1.6.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (0.12.6)
compass-normalize (1.4.3)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
kss (0.5.0)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
ruby (0.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.2.19)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
zurb-foundation (4.3.2)
```

So it seems that I have all of the needed gems. I then looked at my PATH settings via 'echo $PATH' and got the following:

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin
```

I looked into the paths and see that in /usr/bin I have ruby2.0 and in /home/ec2-user/bin I have compass so the installations seem to be in the system PATH.

When I run 'ruby2.0' from the command line I get the following:

```
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:12:in `<class:Builder>':  uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/ext.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1431:in `build_extensions'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in    find_inactive_by_path'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1430:in `build_extensions'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from <internal:abrt_prelude>:2:in `<compiled>'
```

When I run simply 'ruby' nothing ever happens. Is 'grunt compass' looking to find 'ruby' and instead I have 'ruby2.0'? Do I need to create a symlink with ruby -> ruby2.0?

When I run 'compass' from the command line I get:

Usage: compass help [command]

```
Description:
  The Compass Stylesheet Authoring Framework helps you
  build and maintain your stylesheets and makes it easy
  for you to use stylesheet libraries provided by others.
```

Etc.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Just to confirm, Compass works normally when you use it outside of Grunt?  You're able to watch/compile/etc?

Comment: I was able to run 'compass watch' and and the stylesheet was overwritten. However, I did get the following: Errno::EACCES on line ["146"] of /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/themes/theme_name/assets/css/site_styles.css20140430-4672-pmg71i

Answer (score 1):

I've done some researching on this and the following worked for me...

If you have a windows build with Ruby and Compass installed via CLI then try;

- Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings
- Advanced > Environment Variables
- Under System variables search for the 'path' variable which should have a value
- Finally click edit and add `;C:\Ruby193\bin` at the very end of the Variable value.

This should do the trick.

Note that `;C:\Ruby193\bin` refers to the installation of Ruby > Compass on your machine.

If you have a Mac build then perhaps a similar version of fix could work for Mac but I couldn't map that for you, a bit of Googling might help...

Answer (score 0):

`grunt compass` looks for a ruby gem. In your case 'compass -v' gives no error so the compass part works fine. outside this, it doesn't depend on any other component of ruby.

Now that compass is ready, `grunt compass` also looks for a npm module `grunt-contrib-compass` which you would find reference of in a `package.json` file. If you do a `npm install` this npm package gets installed and I believe it should make `grunt compass` work.

Answer (score 0):

grunt-contrib-compass has a bundleExec option that makes the magic. With bundle it will load the gems installed using bundle install. Just set bundleExec: true

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#bundleexec